# In a GroupBox usercontrol, exclude a sub-control on the ControlCollection container?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, class, user-controls

> SCENARIO

I've subclassed a `GroupBox` to customize it, I've added a `CheckBox` on my groupbox header to enable or disable the controls inside the groupbox's control collection.

[image]

> PROBLEM

I consider this a design issue: My checkbox is accesible when iterating the control collection like this:

```
For Each c As Control In Me.ElektroGroupBox1.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is CheckBox Then
        MsgBox(c.Name)
    End If
Next
```

This is because I needed to add the chekbox inside the control collection to make it visible.

> QUESTION

I could do something in my sub-classed `GroupBox` to permanently "exclude" my `CheckBox` when accesing the `ControlCollection` of my custom `GroupBox`?.

> CODE

This is the checkbox related code:

```
public class myGroupbox : inherits groupbox

    Private WithEvents cb As CheckBox

    <Category("Controls")>
    Public ReadOnly Property CheckBox As CheckBox
        Get
            Return Me.cb
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

        Me.CreateCheckBox()

    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateCheckBox()

        Me.cb = New CheckBox
        With Me.cb
            .Name = MyBase.GetType.Name & Me.cb.GetType.Name
            .AutoSize = False
            .Size = New Size(15, 15)
            .Location = New Point(6, 0)
            .Checked = True
        End With

        MyBase.Controls.Add(Me.cb)

    End Sub

    Private Sub CB_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
    Handles cb.CheckedChanged

        Dim checked As Boolean = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Checked

        For Each ctrl As Object In MyBase.Controls

            If Not ctrl.Equals(Me.cb) Then
                ctrl.Enabled = checked
            End If

        Next ctrl

    End Sub
end class
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this ? A workaround would be to override the Paint Event and draw your own CheckBox, CheckedState, Text and BorderFrame. The only option I know of is to `Shadow` the (ReadOnly) Control Property and return another collection.. which is something very wrong to do if you don't implement all appropriate checks..

Comment: Create it as a UserControl and you can prevent the outside world from accessing it at all except by props or methods you provide for that purpose.